# Is there an easy way to get the initialvalue in a textformfield in a variable?

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I just started with flutter and I'm making a profile page and i'm making a request. I'm trying to create an edit profile page so whenever i go there the value's of the textformfield are allready filled in. At first i thought it would be good to use a placeholder for the initialvalue. But i was thinking and this is not good for the user experience. I'd rather have that the textformfields are filled in with the correct data. So if the user wants to update his information the fields are filled in. I'm making a http post request and i get the correct value's back. But the weird thing what i don't get is why i can load the variables in the labeltext But i can't load them in the initialvalue...

I have tried to look for a solution and i have tried a futurebuilder but i couldn't get that to work. I hope someone can help me with this.

```
   Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: new TextFormField(
                                    onSaved: (input) => _voornaam = input,
                                    initialValue: '$voornaam',
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: '$voornaam'),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                flex: 2,
                              ),
```

I expect to get the value of $voornaam in my textformfield. But actually when i load it it just comes back with null. My http request is working because the value is putted in the labeltext. If someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `controller` to your `TextFormField` and in `initState` you can initialise it to the initial value - `_controller = TextEditingController(text: $voornaam);`.

Comment: This was the way i needed it to go. Do you know if there's a way that you can use 1 controller for multiple different initial value's? Thanx anyway hope i will hear from u.

Comment: You should use different controllers for different `TextFormField`s and I would say it is a good practice to deal with controller values only when field is submitted or saved. PS - don't forget to dispose your controller.

Comment: Thanx very much for your fast reply, i will try and practice to deal with the controller that way. But i have to make an edit request so that the user can send his data and doesn't have to type his value all over again if he only want to add 1 letter or something.

Comment: You should be easily able to do that using `controller` :) Also, you can use enabled flag to enable/disable editing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, this code should work:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: App(),
    ));

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  String _voornaam = 'Helo';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // set you _voornaam value
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('text'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: new TextFormField(
          onSaved: (input) => setState(() {
                _voornaam = input;
              }),
          initialValue: '$_voornaam',
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: '$_voornaam'),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```